# How would I build a spring boot rest api project containing embedded reactjs front end code

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, maven, build

I have a spring boot rest api project, using maven, into whose src folder I have a reactjs project. What I need to know is how would I change the pom.xml file so that a jar file is created that is executable for the complete application, both frontend and rest api.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you out: https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e

You just need to run the npm/yarn command from the pom.xml

Here is a sample:

```
        <execution>
        <id>yarn-install</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>yarn</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>install</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>build-frontend</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>yarn</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>build</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this post, I highly encourage you to do a quick search in google before posting questions here

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/